# how to fire job in sql agent in c# in a fire and forget manner

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis, service-broker

We have a ssis pkg that takes 20 mins to complete. (generates a xl report). Users had requested ability to control this pkg via params so we have winforms/c# gui that runs the pkg. (Direct from sql server. We basically call a stored proc that starts a sql job that runs the ssis pkg). So far so good. Now users want to log off after submitting the report request since it does not make sense to wait for 20 mins. (we use citrix vdi. Users loginto specific vdi depending on the apps they want to use, do their tasks and logoff). We are 90% there and just for this functionality service broker seems to be an overkill. I checked with our dba and we have never used service broker till now. Is there someway I can get the ssis pkg to run even if the user closed the winforms app and logged off. (basically sql connection is lost but the fired ssis pkg on sql server must continue to run to completion). thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do  like this add package in job   call proc and leave  it will run

```
CREATE proc startjob
AS
begin
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Weekly Sales Data Backup'
END
```

Comment: from c# to execute proc startjob we need a sqlconnection. As long as the connection is active the job will continue to run. If user closes the winforms app the connection is lost and the running job should terminate. (in theory). I will have to write a sample app to confirm this. thanks

Comment: tested this. I have no idea how it works. Basically even if you close the sql connection the fired job from sp continues to run. Which is what I want. thx